# Any Ideas on a Missing-Columns in a Simple Bootstrap 3.4.1 Table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a very simple 4-column bootstrap table within a responsive grid.  A few customers have reported that the **adLabel** cells/columns are not showing and they don't know what the data means. The only difference between ***adLabel*** and ***adData*** is the font-weight. I thought it was a font issue until this customer sent a screenshot showing that the columns are missing entirely.

[image: Customer screenshot]

Sample Code:

```css
.adLabel {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   color: black;
   text-align: left; 
   vertical-align: top;
   font-weight: normal;
}
.adData {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-3.4.1 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; border:0; padding:5px;">
<tr><td colspan="4" class="bgLightgray center"><h4>Horse Name</h4></td></tr>
<tr><td class="adLabel" style="width:20%">Location</td>
<td class="adData" style="width:30%">Colorado</td>
<td class="adLabel" style="width:20%">Breed</td>
<td class="adData" style="width:30%">Pony</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have ```adLabel``` as ```display: none !important``` ?

Comment: No idea why you sue a framework and then mix inline-style and Head-Style into aswell which will cause varios specificity weight issues..

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 2):

Adblockers are blocking the `adLabel` class. In my case its uBlock.

You just need to rename the class.

Comment: I can't find display: none important! anywhere when I look at the inspector.  I will try renaming the class and see if the customer will respond.  I cannot see the issue in any of my browsers.

Comment: Customer says: "It's perfect!!!!"  Thank you so much JamesDK!